# Selenium webdriver C# - Unable to find the element in a grid developed using angular UI

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a web application developed using angular JS through `selenium webdriver(C#)` and in that i am trying to click on a cell in a angular UI grid, i tried finding by css selector or xpath but it didn't help.

```
Css selector is generating dynamic ID - #\31 460691734316-0-uiGrid-00KQ-cell > div

Xpath is also dynamic //*[@id="1460691734316-0-uiGrid-00KQ-cell"]/div
```

and i tried using

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*[id^='1460'][id$='cell']"));
```

but it didn't help

any help will be highly appreciated. I can send more details if needed

Comment: Confirming by this comment that webdriver on Java is also not handling gracefully markup generated with angular. Few other stackoverflow posts dated within few last months are still without an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For my particular problem with the HTML page containing iframes and developed with AnglularJS the following trick saved me a lot of time: In the DOM I clearly saw that there is an iframe which wraps all the content. So following code supposed to work:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
waitUntilVisibleByXPath("//h2[contains(text(), 'Creative chooser')]");
```

But it was not working and told me something like "Cannot switch to frame. Window was closed". Then I modified the code to:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
waitUntilVisibleByXPath("//h2[contains(text(), 'Creative chooser')]");
```

After this everything went smoothly. So evidently Angular was mangling something with iframes and just after loading the page when you expect that driver is focused on default content it was focused by some already removed by Angular frame. Hope this may help some of you.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to find the element with Selenium IDE which is a plugin of firefox ?

In the IDE, you can easily find the selector using selecting the element with GUI

Comment: I did that too and it is showing the same target in IDE - //div[@id="1460691734316-0-uiGrid-00KQ-cell"]/div

Answer (score 0):

Rather than identifying the element specifically by its ID, could you use the elements around it instead? Is this cell within a table and at a consistent position? Is there a parent element you could more consistently select and iterate through the children in your C# program to identify the appropriate cell you're looking for?

Comment: Yes it is a cell within a table and at a consistent position. The problem is i cannot even find element of the grid to navigate to the children.

Comment: Well, again, I'd suggest looking farther up the parents. Since you've got no explicit identifiers you can use, at some point is there at least a div that's consistently in the same index of a range that you could then dig into, and iteratively filter into the elements to find this cell? It's not the most efficient way, but if you've got no explicit identifiers, you've got to make do.